# How to create data sources with merge fields in them?

Tags: excel, vba, merge

I need ideas to a solution to this problem:

I have an excel sheet where there are a lot of rows used for mail merging. In some cells I need to make individual texts to one or more customers and in that text I need data from the other cells in that/those customers row(s). An example could be this (without the "'s):

You have ordered <<"OrderAmount>> boxes of <<"Color>> <<"flowerType>>.

Which could be converted to this:

You have ordered 3 boxes of green roses.

This was just an example, and some would mean that this could be placed in the Word templete I am merging the information to, but I need these texts to be individual and the real texts I am gonna be using will be much more customer specific.

My own ideas:

1. If it somehow is possible to put a merge field in a cell in excel, then I could merge two times.
2. If I had another cell where I was writing the text as normal and then insert @@color@@ or something like that in that text and have a function that would fill in those informations in the target cell in the customers row. Don't know if it is possible, but I think it is.

Do you have any other suggestions?

Thanks in advance

/Jacob

Comment: Is it always going to be the same text for each customer but with different values inserted? Is it one text per customer row if certain conditions are met in that row? I'm thinking of building the text using the concatenation operator.

Comment: No its never the same text, its a individual text we put together to each customer, where we would like to be able to use the data in excel itself.

Comment: Do you have sample data? Can you post it here? Possibly as an image or maybe Google docs? Even just a text link to somewhere on the Web? I'm busy all day today but could possibly look at it in around 17 hours. All I'm thinking of doing is some form of VLOOKUP coupled with & operator which is used to concatenate strings and data and suchlike.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I have now figured it out myself.

What I did was using the SUBSTITUTE function. I then write my individual text in a cell and insert the variables for each data line in my datasheet.

The text I am writing could look like this:

"Hello Mr. @@lastname@@. Can you confirm that your adresse is @@road@@ @@housenumber@@, @@zipcode@@, @@state@@?"

I then in another cell have this code:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(Sheet2!$F$7;"@@lastname@@";Sheet2!B3);Sheet2!$F$7;"@@road@@";Sheet2!C3);Sheet2!$F$7;"@@housenumber@@";Sheet2!D3)....and so on...
```

Now the $F$7 cell is where the individual text including the variables are located.

The B3, C3 and D3 are the cells containing the information from that particular customer.

The above code goes into each customers row in another column in the datasheet(the sheet I am merging from).

Hope someone else is getting some use of this. It surely did it for me.

/Jacob